# What is the matter with my package manager?

Tags: dpkg

My system encounters an error every time after installing new software:

```
sh: 1: /bin/echo: Permission denied
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke '/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

What is the matter with my package manager?

```
stat /bin/echo
  File: /bin/echo
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 3932206     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (   43/    utmp)
Access: 2018-12-01 08:03:07.846890937 +0800
Modify: 2018-12-01 08:03:07.846890937 +0800
Change: 2018-12-01 08:03:07.846890937 +0800
 Birth: -
```

My Operating System information:

```
uname -a
Linux hwy 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What does `stat /bin/echo` say? `echo` is also a shell builtin (in at least bash and zsh), so you wouldn't notice quickly if you removed permissions on `/bin/echo` by accident.

Comment: Did you do this?: [Accidentally changing permission of '/' directory to 'chmod 660 '](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/287000)

Comment: You have done something unfortunate to your `/bin/echo`. `stat` says it's zero bytes and not executable, neither should be the case. On Debian `/bin/echo` comes from the coreutils package, so you could try to reinstall that with `apt install --reinstall coreutils`. I have no idea whether that actually works for essential packages (like coreutils), and in any case it's probably a sign that you've done something bad to your system, so it might just delay the probably inevitable reinstallation.

Comment: Although we can only see echo's problem here. But I'm pretty sure you broke your system by accident but you didn't tell us what you've done. The best suggestion would just be re-install your system.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
sudo apt autoremove
stat  /bin/echo
  File: /bin/echo
  Size: 31464       Blocks: 64         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 3932296     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-12-17 18:41:38.876797380 +0800
Modify: 2017-02-22 20:23:45.000000000 +0800
Change: 2018-12-17 18:41:32.229517688 +0800
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Okay, so you managed to get a normal `/bin/echo` by reinstalling the coreutils package, then that will hopefully not cause you any more problems. But without knowedge of how your `/bin/echo` ended up that way, you have no idea what other errors are in your installation.

Comment: No record in `history`,i forgot.